# Is there a way to monitor Node.JS applications performance?

Tags: javascript, node.js, profiling

I'm new to Node.JS and wonder, is there a way to monitor the performance and see what is the bottleneck of my application and which DB transaction is taking most of the time,...

Comment: Have you tried http://spy-js.com/

It is also integrated into the Webstorm IDE from Jetbrains

Comment: I reworded my question, could you please make it open?

Comment: Should I reword it and create a new question?

Answer (score 0):

Below are the useful profilers and most widely used for Node.js

**Google’s V8** has built-in **sample based profiling**. Profiling is turned off by default, but can be enabled via the --prof command line option. The sampler records stacks of both JavaScript and C/C++ code mostly piped into a log file. The Linux tick processor script that ships with V8 can be used to analyze the sample to determine if the CPU time is being consumed at the OS level libraries or within the application itself. Limited sequencing is also provided.

Fine below link will give you better understanding

[Profile your web application with V8’s internal profiler](https://developers.google.com/v8/profiler_example)

**Client-side CPU profiling**

The internal profiler is also available as part of the **Chrome Dev Tools** and lets you collect and analyze the CPU profile of an application within the JavaScript console. However, this is only good for client side analysis.

[image: Client Side CPU Profiling in Chrome]

For Server Side Profiling

**Server-side CPU profiling**

The V8 profiler has been extended by StrongLoop to provide deep diagnostics and visual snapshotting across any application process in both clustered and non-clustered mode at any point of time. Take for example a Node app which is running as a single master, two worker process cluster. Let’s startup the application, put some load on it and run the profiler.
Startup the cluster

Here we are using the slc run command with clustering option and specifying the number of CPU cores to be attached.

[image: Startup the cluster]

Get loaded!

By using Jmeter script to simulate 100 simultaneous users on the clustered app. We’ll go with an ideal case, where each application instance/CPU core is handling a 50 users workload.

[image: Jmeter script to simulate]